# Enable a Local Group Policy Via Command Line?

Tags: command-line, windows-10, group-policy, onedrive

I'm attempting to disable OneDrive on some new machines my client has acquired. They are all (about 200 in total) running Windows 10 Pro (unfortunately not enterprise). I'm trying to figure out a way to enable the "Prevent the usage of OneDrive for file storage" policy under "Local Computer Policy\Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\OneDrive" from the command line. Unfortunately it's a bit time consuming to individually go into gpedit.msc browse through and enable it on each machine.

Any suggestions?

Comment: So are these 200 computers not on a domain?

Comment: They are spread across two domains. The ideal scenario would have been to simply push the policies down to the selected groups, but the global IT organization (not to be confused with the business unit's IT staff) as a policy doesn't want to help facilitate anything. At this point we are just trying to roll out some new machines (to get XP out of the field).

Answer (score 1):

If these computers are not in a domain for some reason, you can use this command to disable OneDrive.

```
reg add "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\OneDrive" /v "DisableFileSyncNGSC" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

This has to be run as administrator. "DisableFileSyncNGSC" corresponds to "Prevent the usage of OneDrive for file storage" GPO.